# XCode iOS operator new custom implementation

Tags: ios, exception, xcode4.2, new-operator

XCode issues warning for my implementation of global operator new:

```
void *operator new(size_t blocksize);
```

It says: 'operator new' is missing exception specification 'throw(std::bad_alloc)'

But my implementation does not intend to throw any exception, and I'd rather declare it as

```
void *operator new(size_t blocksize) throw();
```

However, the latter implementation leads to an error:

*Exception specification in declaration does not match previous declaration*

So, the question is: am I really forced (to calm down XCode compiler) to declare a custom 'operator new' as throw(std::bad_alloc) even if it wont throw any exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the question is: am I really forced (to calm down XCode compiler)
>   to declare a custom 'operator new' as throw(std::bad_alloc) even if it
>   wont throw any exception?

Yes you do:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2185/_index.html

> For complete control and portability, if you replace any of these signatures, you should replace all of them. However the default implementation of the array forms simply forward to the non-array forms. If you only replace the four non-array forms, expect the default array forms to forward to your replacements.